# Convert from ISO-2022-JP-2 to UTF-8 in Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, utf-8, ruby-2.1

I have a ISO-2022-JP-2 string and need to convert it to UTF-8, but I am getting an error.

To be more concrete: I am trying to read an email which is transferred using quoted-printable. This email contains the word `tōtatsu` (notice the accent above the o) and I am converting the given text like this:

```
given = "t=1B$(D+W=1B(Btatsu"
text = given.unpack("M*").first   #convert from quoted-printable
```

Basically this will replace `=1B` with the proper `\e` escape character and the string in `text` becomes `t␛$(D+W␛(Btatsu`.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0202) that `␛$(D` is used to switch to [JIS X 0212-1990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0212) and likewise `␛(B` is used to switch back to ASCII. Notice that `␛$(D` is new in ISO-2022-JP-2, it is **not** part of the original ISO-2022-JP.

However, the encoding of the string is still ASCII, so I guess I have to force the proper encoding since Ruby has no way of knowing that the actual string is ISO-2022-JP-2?

```
puts text.encoding # ASCII-8BIT
text = text.force_encoding('iso-2022-jp-2')
```

Now it turns out that

```
text.encode('utf-8')
```

is not able to convert the given string: `code converter not found (ISO-2022-JP-2 to UTF-8) (Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError)`

How can I convert this string to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Ruby 2.1 does not support `iso-2022-jp-2` encoding:

```
>> "t\e$(D+W\e(Btatsu".encode('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')
=> "t\e$(D+W\e(Btatsu"

>> "t\e$(D+W\e(Btatsu".encode('utf-8', 'iso-2022-jp-2')
Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError: code converter not found (ISO-2022-JP-2 to UTF-8)
        from (irb):1:in `encode'
        from (irb):1
        from /home/falsetru/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

You can use `iconv` instead:

```
require 'iconv'
Iconv.conv('utf-8', 'iso-2022-jp-2', "t\e$(D+W\e(Btatsu")
# => "tōtatsu"
```

Comment: whenever you appeared, *problem* themselves fall in *problem*. You know why? - Because *problems* get to know, they will be now wipped out by you :-)